# Set a field to required based on a selection in another field Dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Is there any function in java script to make a field to required dynamically?.

Problem : Based on the selected values of dropdownlist other field should required or readonly and non  required.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ABC" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataSourceID="ABCDataSource" EnableTheming="True"
                 Width="100%" ClientInstanceName="gridABC">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn Caption="Actions" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" 
                        VisibleIndex="0">
                        <EditButton Visible="True">
                        </EditButton>
                  </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                  <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn  Caption="Card Type" FieldName="TypeCard" 
                            ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4" >
                            <PropertiesComboBox Width="120px">
                                <Items>
                                    <dx:ListEditItem Text="A" Value="0" />
                                    <dx:ListEditItem Text="B" Value="1" />
                                </Items>
                            </PropertiesComboBox>
                   </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                   <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Name"  FieldName="Name" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" 
                        VisibleIndex="2" Width="100px">
                        <PropertiesTextEdit MaxLength="30" Width="100px">
                        </PropertiesTextEdit>
                        <EditFormSettings ColumnSpan="1" VisibleIndex="2" />
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Contact"  FieldName="Contact" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" 
                        VisibleIndex="3" Width="100px">
                        <PropertiesTextEdit MaxLength="30" Width="100px">
                        <ValidationSettings>
                                <RequiredField ErrorText="Contact" IsRequired="False" />
                      </ValidationSettings>
                        </PropertiesTextEdit>
                        <EditFormSettings ColumnSpan="1" VisibleIndex="3" />
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
           </Columns>
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
    </div>                                          
</form>
```

**There is 3 fields, if i select the value "A" from "Card Type" drop down list  then other two fields should be required , if i select "B" from drop down list then both two fields should be not mandatory and Read only with gray color.**

Comment: Basically the answer to your question is "yes, this is possible." If you were to share your relevant HTML, explain which options should trigger the various states of the other element (and which other element you're trying to manipulate) then we could offer something more useful and helpful.

Comment: I added my inputs, Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What HTML does that produce in the browser? Which options should change what other input(s)? Added [tag:asp.net] on the assumption that's what you're using, please revise and adjust if it's something else.

Comment: Sorry i don't have much idea about your question- "What HTML does that produce in the browser?"